# AWS Lambda throttled queue processing

Tags: queue, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis, rate-limiting

I plan to fetch a list of records from a web service which limits the number of requests that can be made within a certain time frame.

My idea was to setup a simple pipeline like this:

`List of URLs -> Lambda Function to fetch JSON -> S3`

The part I'm not sure about is how to feed the list of URLs in rate/time limited blocks, e.g take 5 URLs and spawn 5 lambda functions every second.

Ideally I'd like to start this by uploading/sending/queueing the list once and then just let it do it's thing on its own until it has processed the queue completely.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the problem in two parts.

1. Trigger: Lambda supports a wide variety. Look for Using AWS Lambda to process AWS events in [Lambda FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs).

I personally would go with Dynamo DB. But S3 will come in a close second.

There might be other options using other streams like Kinesis, but these seem simpler by far.

2. Throttling: You can set [limits on number of lambda instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#concurrent-execution-safety-limit).

---

So e.g. if you go with DDB:

- You'll dump all your URLs in to a table one row per URL.
- This will create events, one per row.
- Each event triggers one Lambda call.
- Number of parallel Lambda executions/instances are limited by config.